# Why is my identifer invalid in my code?

Tags: plsql

```
INSERT INTO Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_Id,Name, Reset_Shipping_Date)
VALUES(50295656, 'Ricky Riveras',TO_DATE( '010308', 'MMDDYY'));


INSERT INTO Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_Id,Name, Reset_Shipping_Date)
VALUES(4507655, 'Bobby Heenan',TO_DATE( '050998', 'MMDDYY'));


INSERT INTO Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_Id,Name, Reset_Shipping_Date)
VALUES(3747547, 'Jim Johnson',TO_DATE( '070969', 'MMDDYY'));


INSERT INTO Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_Id,Name, Reset_Shipping_Date)
VALUES(8432525, 'Joshua Trinite',TO_DATE( '070909', 'MMDDYY'));


INSERT INTO Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_Id,Name, Reset_Shipping_Date)
VALUES(943252, 'Dusty Rhodes',TO_DATE( '100999', 'MMDDYY'));
```

Error that I get:

> INSERT INTO Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_Id,Name,
>   reset_Shipping_Date)
>                                                              *
>
> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00904: "RESET_SHIPPING_DATE": invalid identifier
>
> INSERT INTO Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_Id,Name,
>   Reset_Shipping_Date)
>                                                              *
>
> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00904: "RESET_SHIPPING_DATE": invalid identifier
>
> INSERT INTO Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_Id,Name,
>   Reset_Shipping_Date)
>                                                              *
>
> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00904: "RESET_SHIPPING_DATE": invalid identifier
>
> INSERT INTO Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_Id,Name,
>   Reset_Shipping_Date)
>                                                              *
>
> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00904: "RESET_SHIPPING_DATE": invalid identifier
>
> INSERT INTO Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_Id,Name,
>   Reset_Shipping_Date)
>                                                              *
>
> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00904: "RESET_SHIPPING_DATE": invalid identifier

Comment: Are you sure RESET_SHIPPING_DATE is a valid column name in your table?

Comment: Check the data type of RESET_SHIPPING_DATE column also check column name spelling.